# TypeInterceptor Implementation in StructureMap 4.6

Tags: structuremap

Can someone help me to convert the below line of code from StructureMap 2.6 to Structure Map 4.6

```
public class EventAggregatorInterceptor : TypeInterceptor
{
    public object Process(object target, IContext context)
    {
        IEventPublisher eventPublisher = context.GetInstance<IEventPublisher>();
        eventPublisher.RegisterHandlers(target);
        return target;
    }
    public bool MatchesType(Type type)
    {
        bool matchesType = type.ImplementsInterfaceTemplate(typeof(IEventHandler<>));
        return matchesType;
    }
}
```

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, below is the code

```
public class EventListenerRegistration : IInterceptorPolicy
{
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return "Adds the constructed object to the EventAggregator";
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IInterceptor> DetermineInterceptors(Type pluginType, Instance instance)
    {
        if (instance.ReturnedType.FindInterfacesThatClose(typeof(IEventHandler<>)).Any())
        {
            Expression<Action<IContext, object>> register = (c, o) => c.GetInstance<IEventPublisher>().RegisterHandlers(o);
            yield return new ActivatorInterceptor<object>(register);
        }
    }
}
```

And then I register it inside my Registry constructor

```
Policies.Interceptors(new EventListenerRegistration());
```